# How to store credentials for basic HTTP authenication into the database on server side?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, basic-authentication

For learning purposes, I have created a simple PHP application which implements a web service with a basic authentication mechanism. I know that basic authentication is not the best mechanism, but I just want to start with this mechanism before I start with OAuth2.0 or something else.

So my current environment looks like this:

Multiple clients provide data in JSON representation only over an https connection.

- Client 1: https://example1.com/api/data/
- Client 2: https://example2.com/api/data/
- ...

These resources are protected through a basic authentication header and the clients provide data only if the credentials are valid:

```
public function provideData()
{
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Example BasicAuth"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        die('Authentication failed');
    }

    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    // not relevant database stuff ...

    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $saltDb);

    if (!hash_equals($password, $passwordDb)) {
        die('Authentication failed');
    }

    // not relevant data handling stuff ...

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

So every client stores his own credentials into a client database and provides data only if the entered data is valid. (I don't want to store credentials as plain text into the client database so I store salted hashed passwords.). This is working great for me, but now comes the part where I got into trouble:

There is a server which should collect the data of all these clients. For this reason, I can create multiple client objects on the server side which contains data like the resource URL, username, password and so on, but I don't want to store the client passwords as plain text into the server database, but I can't store hashed client passwords on server side too, because the server will don't know about the real password then.

So I think the only solution is to implement a custom encrypt and decrypt function to store an encrypted client password into the server database. Then only the server knows about encryption and decryption and could handle this or is there a better way to store the required client credentials on the server side?

**EDIT**

I will try to clarify "the server will don't know about the real password". Please interrupt me if I am wrong, but a basic HTTP authentication will use plain client data (username and password) and sends a base64 encoded string of them, e.g. "Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" to get access to the resource. For this reason, the server has to use the password as plaintext to build a request with a basic authentication header.

The problem is when I create a client object on the server side, then I have to store the credentials into the server database and I could hash the password there, but hash functions are one-way functions so the server will not be able to get the plain password from the hashed password back, without storing the plain password too, but if the server needs the plain password to get access to the resource then I can't use a hash function to "protect" the password into the database.

Comment: Hashing is not Encryption, it's often called that either naively or because of vernacular ( people are used to interchanging the terms, like function and method, or motor and engine ).  That said you should encrypt them using something like AES, symmetric encryption.  Or better if possible asymmetric, OpenSSL.  I'd say PGP, but PHP has poor support for that one.

Comment: Please clarify: "because the server will don't know about the real password" - why the server has to know the real password? Also, php has password_hash and password_verify functions for password hashing and checking.

Comment: @OlegLoginov - because if the server cannot decode the credentials it cant use them with a third party API,  this is not user passwords.  Think like sFTP credentials.

Comment: I have edited my question and I hope I could clarify your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP basic authentication requires plaintext credentials which have to be base64 encoded. So the server has to store the plaintext credentials per client into the database for example if this should work, **BUT** this is really bad, because if someone steals the server database then he got access to the data of all clients. To obscure, the passwords leads to security through obscurity and is not really better.

So this is the wrong way to go. It seems that HTTP basic authentication is not suitable for a machine-to-machine communication via a REST API and I have to use a proper and secure mechanism like OAuth2.0 or @ArtisticPhoenix suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do ( which I probably don't )  it seems like a good fit for asymmetric encryption ( like RSA )

Asymmetric encryption has 2 keys, a public and a private key:

- public key can decode only stuff encrypted by private key
- private key can decode only stuff encrypted by public key

This seems to meet what you would need:

1. You can encrypted the password with public key on the client
2. You can store the encrypted password in a client database
3. You can securely send the encrypted password to the server
4. The server can decode it using it's private key
5. Many clients can all use the same public key, making it easier to deploy.
6. Any given client cannot decode another clients password, as only the private key can decode stuff encoded by the public key.

A quick implementation using `openSSL` ( you have to enable and extension for this ) and certificates ( this an be a self signed cert )

**Public key** implementation on the client:

```
public function asymEncodePublic($string){
    //public cert
    $file = __DIR__.'/public/server.crt';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $fp = fopen($file,"r");
        $public_key = fread($fp,8192);
        openssl_get_publickey(public_key);
        fclose($fp);

        //var to store output
        $crypttext = '';
        openssl_public_encrypt($string, $crypttext, $pub_key);
        //convert from bin to hex
        $crypttext = bin2hex($crypttext);
        return $crypttext;
    }
}
```

**Private key** implementation on the server:

```
public function asymDecodePrivate($crypttext){
    //private key
    $file = __DIR__.'/private/server.key';
    if(file_exists($file)){         
        $fp = fopen($file,"r");
        $private_key = fread($fp,8192);
        openssl_get_publickey($private_key);
        fclose($fp);
        //convert hex to bin
        $crypttext = hex2bin($crypttext);
        //var to store output
        $decrypted = '';
        //decrypt
        openssl_private_decrypt($crypttext, $decrypted, $private_key);

        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

One thing if I remember correctly, the length of data you can encrypt (with openSSL) at one time is based on the complexity of the certificate.  So for example with a 2048 cert you might be able to only encrypt up `256` bytes at a time. It's been a while sense I had to deal with this stuff, so I don't remember exactly.

**A few notes**
Somethings are not clear to me.

> because the server will don't know about the real password then

Does the server really need to know the "real" password.  The only reason I could think that the server would need to know, is if the password is for a 3rd party application.  An example would be sFTP on the clients machine.

This could be used for pulling or putting files on the remote client from the server.  In this case the server would always need access to a plain text version of the password.  So it can login to the remote machine. In this case there is no real way to secure it 100%.  You can make it more difficult. For example with OpenSSL a hacker would need the encrypted password, the private key, and possibly your implementation of OpenSSL encryption.

**Disclaimer:**

> For learning purposes, I have created a simple PHP application

I don't claim to be a cryptography expert ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think your solution is currently a little bit too much. I have edited my question and maybe it was not clear enough that I was asking about HTTP basic authentication. A public/ private key authentication is currently not what I am looking for, but thank you anyway.

Comment: No problem I don't mind...  I tend to go a bit overboard on explanations, I guess that happens when you deal with a lot of support/help desk things, and junior developers... lol

Comment: Are the client and server, separate machines?  or does this all happen on one?

Comment: The clients and the server are separate machines.

Comment: Seems like my idea would still work, I wasn't meaning logging in with the password encrypted in OpenSSL, I was meaning saving it in the server's DB encrypted with the `public key`.  ie. `The problem is when I create a client object on the server side, then I have to store the credentials into the server database`

Comment: As I said in my answer there is no way to protect it 100%.  Lets assume you can store it as a hash, and login with the hash.  Then all I need to do is steal the hash, and I can login.  As a 'hacker' I don't care if it's hashed already or not.  The best you can do is force them to access, the DB, your code, and the key.  They need 3 things, instead of 1 ( the stored hash or plain password )

Comment: For example if they steal only the DB and all the passwords are encrypted with OpenSSL.  It does them no good, without returning to the server to get your private key, and the code you use to encrypt it ( you can include other things in the data besides the password ).    Append a few random letters after it's encrypted and it's impossible to decode without knowing where that was added.

Comment: But if they steal a DB of hashes, and they can login with the Hashes, they might as well have gotten the plaintext password.

Comment: Yeah, but the steps "3. You can securely send the encrypted password to the server" and "4. The server can decode it using it's private key" are steps which I don't need so far. The clients don't know about the server and you can access the data on every client without the server if you know the resource URL and the credentials.

Comment: I won't argue but you do need 4, `then I have to store the credentials into the server database`  You would decode it on the server before using it, this way the server `knows` the password.  But it has some level of protection when stored there.  If it's stored on the server encrypted, one could argue the server would need a way to decode it.

Comment: And for 3, The server cant create credentials on the client, if it's accessing them remotely, right?  So the client would create the credentials and somehow this has to be sent to the server.  Even if `the server goes and gets them from the client` it's still sending them to the server...

Comment: And last, I wouldn't call them steps.  They are features, I guess I could have used a bullet list.  But just because something allows you to do A, B, C, and D.  Doesn't mean you have to do all of them...  Steps would be 1. do this, 2. then do that, 3 next do this other thing.  These are separate.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but login with hashes will not work after all. RFC 2617 requires that in HTTP Basic authentication, the username and password must be encoded with base64. So it seems that the server could only get access if he will send the credentials in plain text via HTTP basic authentication header.

Comment: As I said a hash wouldn't matter,  I would just steal that and use it to login.  It's the same as using plain text, because there is no `transformation` of the login 'password'.

Comment: "So the client would create the credentials and somehow this has to be sent to the server."... not really^^, the workflow is currently like someone creates a client object with username and password on the client machine, after that the resource is protected through basic authentication. Some other one knows about the client resource URL and the credentials without a handshake between the client and server and creates an independent client object on the server side with the same credentials and the resource URL.

Comment: "As I said a hash wouldn't matter, I would just steal that and use it to login.", but how you wanna login if the password is hashed? You still need the real password to log in and not only the hash?

Comment: Why you asking me? that was your idea ( to login with a hash) or you wouldn't be checking RFC 2617.  I was simply saying even if you could log in using a hash, its no benefit.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I thought we already found out that is nonsense.

Comment: So I can't protect the server side stored client credentials without an additional handshake between client and server, right? Suppose I obscure the password on server side with a custom encrypt function that only the server knows, then the server will be able to store a password like "badPass"  as an encrypted password like "2u3bdsajd8281had28d" into the database and will be able to decrypt this password, because the server knows the encrypt function. So if someone steals the database he has to found out the encrypt function to get the real password. Then this is security through obscurity?

Comment: `Then this is security through obscurity` - that is true

Comment: the other option is `before I start with OAuth2.0`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patience and time. I think that answers my question.